# Allow only one keyword that is not "None" in **kwargs

Tags: python

I would like to explain my problem with an example.
(The example I gave may not make much sense in itself, but I thought it would be better understood this way.)

```py
def animal(*args, **kwargs):
    duck = kwargs.get("duck")
    lion = kwargs.get("lion")
    wolf = kwargs.get("wolf")
    # bear, fish, bee etc...
    
    
    if duck:
        if lion or wolf:
            raise ValueError("When 'duck' is specified, you cannot value other arguments.")
        print(f"Duck: {duck}!")
    elif lion:
        if duck or wolf:
            raise ValueError("When 'lion' is specified, you cannot value other arguments.")
        print(f"Lion: {lion}!")
    elif wolf:
        if duck or lion:
            raise ValueError("When 'wolf' is specified, you cannot value other arguments.")
        print(f"Wolf: {wolf}!")
    
    # other stuff ...

animal()  # ✓
animal(duck="quack")  # ✓
animal(duck="quack", lion=None)  # ✓
animal(duck="quack", lion="roar")  # X
```

As the arguments increase, the amount of "or" also increases. Is there a better way to achieve same result?

Comment: `kwargs` is a dict, so you can just write `if len(kwargs) > 1:`. That will work if you aren't expecting users to call your function like `animal(duck='Donald', wolf=None)`, otherwise you could filter out the `None` values from the dict first.

Comment: @kaya3 upvote.  thank you, it is a great idea but I am more curious about filtering out `None`s.

Comment: ```if (list(kwargs.values()).count(True)) >= 2``` would work: with kwargs.values() you get a list of all values in a dict in the form of a ```dict_values([...])```. Concatenated to a list, and counting the times ```True``` is in it, you can see if more than one was selected. This might not be as simple as Kaya3's solution but it could be modified to work with different scenarios where kwargs is supposed to have more than just one item.

Comment: `kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs if v is not None}`

Comment: You might consider using `functools.singledispatch` or a dict like `{'duck': do_duck_stuff, 'lion': do_lion_stuff, ...}` instead of a bunch of mutually exclusive keyword arguments.

Comment: Also, this is a made-up example, right? So what's the real function supposed to do? Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832); give context.

Comment: @wjandrea yes, it is a made-up example but my problem is exact same with this scenario and I got really good solutions. The thing is all of solutions are comment so I can not mark as an accepted answer.

Comment: @MustafaAHCI My point is, what are you trying to accomplish by doing this? Maybe someone has already solved the same problem and we wouldn't know because you're asking about something tangential.

Comment: This code returns different error messages messages based on what combination of animals are present in kwargs.  Do you care about preserving that behavior?  Or is a generic "You can't do that" message enough?

Comment: @wjandrea This is actually a math solution about vectors. It produces solutions according to the argument it contains and its type. So only one argument should be used or not at all (return 0). I thought it would be more understandable to just write animals instead of writing complicated math terms here. (There may be a better way to do this but that's not the problem I am asking)

Comment: @JohnGordon it is a really good question, thank you. it is not that much important but that would be nice if I could do it without making the code too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, you can count the number of non-None values in kwargs, and raise an exception if that number is greater than one.

```
x = 0
for val in kwargs.values():
    if val is not None:
        x += 1
    if x > 1:
        raise ValueError("Too many values present")
```